# Fire modal after 1 minute user session

Tags: javascript, local-storage, session-storage

I'm trying to fire a modal after user spends 1 minute on my website. First I tried `setTimeout` method but then I realized the counter would reset when user refresh website or visit another page:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    modal.fadeIn(300); 
}, 60000);
```

As I googled, I think the right solution would be to use the `sessionStorage`, but I do not know how to use it. Can somebody help?

Comment: Local storage or a cookie could also work, but sessionStorage is probably indeed the most appropriate. The thing is, instead of setting the timer to 1 minute from now, you need to set it to 1 minute from the time they first arrived on your site. That value you need to store somewhere (anywhere), and before setting the timer you need to fetch the value, do the math, and set the timer. If you found `sessionStorage`, you probably also found [some examples on how to use it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). If you run into a specific problem, let us know. :-)

Comment: @GolezTrol That is the case :) I was not able to find examples of using it like this. I only found out how to set and get items in `sessionStorage`

Comment: And that's all you need to do. Check if the value exists. If so, read it and use it. If not, write the current time to it. sessionStorage, like everything else, is just a piece of Lego. You decide how to put the pieces together and what to build with it.

Answer (score 0):

Same as localStorage，you can set a key +1 per second。

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  sessionStorage.setItem("counter"，sessionStorage.getItem("counter")+1); 
}, 60000);
```

Browser will remember the last value of "counter" even after a refresh.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. I have never used session or local storage. Where can I call the event then in this code?